# Real time validation for input using JQuery validator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 parameters called name and id which are fetched through UI using following code:

```
<div class="style1 validateName">
   <label>Name : </label>
<input type="text" id="name"/>
</div>
<div class="style2 validateId">
   <label>Id : </label>
<input type="text" id="id_number"/>
</div>
```

I need to validate to ensure that name does not contain any trailing space and id field is always filled.

I have validator as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod('validateName', function(inText, element) {
        return (inText.length == inText.trim().length);
    },'Cannot have space within name');

    $.validator.addMethod('validateId', function(number, element) {
        return (number != "");
    },'It should be submitted');
}
```

But it works only when the first validator get triggered. That means if there are space in name and it catches it after only, no id submission is caught. What could be the issue

Comment: Please add the code to show how do you attach the inputs to this validator?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Am calling it within <div class="">

Comment: Where are you going to use this validation? on button click?

Comment: It should not allow to add without those validations as well, if we tab to next coloumn or click somewhere else without value it shoud pop-up the above mentioned message.

Comment: Jquery validator required method is also possible for second case of testing ids, but it also not working :(